# Mis proyectos tienen problemas con Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio

> > Gradle project sync failed. Basic funcionality will not work property
>
> ! C:\Users\HP\Desktop\problema.png

¿Que puedo hacer? No puedo correr mis proyectos en android studio. 
Ya probe actualizando y descargando todos los complementos, activar los complementos del SDK, descargue el Gradle correspodiente a la version por aparte para colocarlo en el directorio de Android pero no me corre nada.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme

Comment: Hace falta mas detalles ... cambiaste la version de gradle por ejemplo?

Comment: Podrías agregar tu Grandle por favor.

Comment: Chirstoper, agrega tu Gradle sino sera imposible. Tambien intenta agregar mas detalles del error y hasta una captura de pantalla del error nos serviria para diagnosticar el error.